# No agrega datos en tabla php

Tags: php, mysql

Creo un formulario, porque este formulario no los enviaron y la verdad no me habia sucedido algo asi y es por eso que opte por pedir ayuda ya que no encuentro tanta informacion

```
<form method="POST" action="agregar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="NOMBRE" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="@E-MAIL" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="telefono" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="TELEFONO" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="foto" class="custom-file">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="boton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Guardar Cambios"/> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

en la pagina de agregar.php tengo esto

```
    <?php
    include "conexion.php";
    if($_POST){
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];

        $nombreimg=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
        $archivo=$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];

        $ruta="fotos/".$nombreimg;
        move_uploaded_file($archivo,$ruta);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO datos (nombre,email, telefono, foto) VALUES ('$nombre','$email','$telefono','$ruta')";
        $conn->query($sql);

        header('location:index.php');
    }
?>
```

pero cuando le doy guardar informacion no me aparece en la misma pagina

```
<?php
            include "conexion.php";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["nombre"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["email"]."</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>".$row["telefono"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='$row[foto]' width='25'/></td>";
                    echo "<td> <a href='detalles.php?dato=$row[id]' class='badge badge-success'>Detalle</a> 
                    <a href='borrar.php?dato=$row[id]' class='badge badge-danger'>Eliminar</a>
                    <a href='editar.php?dato=$row[id]' class='badge badge-warning'>Actualizar</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Pero no lo logro encontrar error alguien me puede asesorar por favor, tal vez el error sea en el select pero asi es como no lo mandaron y no me habia tocado tener esa situacion alguna vez

Comment: El formulario siempre te va a mandar a otra pagina porque ese es el comportamiento por defecto de un formulario, en este caso siempre te va enviar a la pagina que tengas definida en el action, si deseas que eso no pase deberas usar ajax.

Comment: Por cierto, que usas??, mysqli o PDO??

Comment: uso mysqli y pues la verdad no habia hecho esto anteriormente.

Comment: Ahí no estás guardando información sino seleccionandola

Comment: @BetaM nos dieron el mismo archivo pero yo tampoco entiendo porque se selecciona

Comment: No estás mostrando todo el código del archivo agredar.php. Y si lo estás mostrando entero, en ningún momento estás insertando los datos.

Comment: @BrahimKhallota lo acabe de actualizar

Comment: Hay una cosa mas, podrias agregar el código HTML completo de tu formulario?, puede ser que alguno de los campos no coincidan con los recibidos en POST de php, y pasa que si los campos añadidos no tienen un formato valido para ser insertados en MySQL pues la consulta sera rechazada...

Comment: @Riven lo actualice entonces la sentencia de select la cambiaria por INSERT INTO  ?

Comment: No no, no la cambies, solo que para ese entonces no habia ninguna sentencia INSERT y pense que te habias confundido con tu sentencia SELECT, pero ese no es el problema, ya que si tienes una sentencia INSERT en tu codigo original.

Comment: @Riven la cambie en el codigo de aqui y en el original pero no me inserta los datos y ya estuve buscandole pero no encuentro la falla (la deje como estaba SELECT * FROM...)

Comment: El tercer extracto de código pertenece al archivo index.php? por que en agregar.php al finalizar estas redireccionando a index.php

Comment: @DarkFrostnight bueno asi nos menciono el maestro pero en realidad no funciona no se si vaya ahi ?